# Android studio :open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apache-poi

I have this method. The problem is that in Android studio the excel path doesn't exist, but if I use the code in IntelliJ it works perfectly fine. Please help me to understand this issue.
I have this in manifest too:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

````
   private static String findRow(String cellContent) throws IOException {
        String excelPath="C:\\Users\\mely\\AndroidStudioProjects\\exportingfile.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(excelPath);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        for (Row row : sheet) {
            for (Cell cell : row) {
                if (cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString().trim().equals(cellContent)) {
                    return sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()).getCell(9).toString();
                }

            }
        }
        return "";
    } ```
````

Comment: It will exist for Android Studio. But not for an Android app on an Android device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > ="C:\Users\mely\AndroidStudioProjects\exportingfile.xlsx"

C: is a partition on a hard disk on a Windows PC.

It is not a valid storage path on an Android device.

Your app on an Android device has no access to files on a Windows PC.

Not to your PC, not to mines.

Comment: Life saving. I am very new on mobile dev and I thought it's gonna work like this for some reasons. Thank you a lot.

Comment: Put your .xlsx file in assets directory of your project. Then at runtime you can use it as resource.